# what is the result of SQL injection attack to a system without a database?

Tags: sql, nosql, sql-injection

Actually I am working in a web application that interacts with some other systems, but there is no actually a DB system, for some reason it was designed in that form, the topic here is that somebody tried to execute some security scan and with the tool Arachni performed some Blind NoSql and Blind SQL injection, according to this person, the system is vulnerable to this kind of attacks based on the scanner tool, but my question is.

There is a real risk of something if there is no exist database? an attacker can have some other privilege using this kind of attack?

Comment: It's true SQL injection is not possible if you don't use SQL. That goes without saying. But it's possible for NoSQL to have security risks too.

Comment: There are other security issues unrelated to databases that you need to educate yourself about. Visit https://owasp.org for information, or read a book like [24 Deadly Sins of Software Security: Programming Flaws and How to Fix Them](https://www.amazon.com/Deadly-Sins-Software-Security-Programming/dp/0071626751/). There's too much information for a Stack Overflow answer.

Answer (score 3):

SQL injection attacks only work with databases. If your system can't provide an anwser to an SQL query you don't have to worry at all about this.

I have no idea what kind of web aplication you have developed (you didn't give any information) but, even if you have an actual database, the sql injection code must works, and that's impossible with no database.

Comment: That is what I thought, but my manager told me to investigate if the were some other risk, for example with sessions or something like that, for me there is no point, but as I dont know so much about security I wanted to ask  and see all the options, I guess the same applies for Blind NoSql and Blind SQL injection, right?